# How to use a Hamming window in the frequency domain?

Tags: signal-processing

In "Principles of computerized tomographic imaging" by Kak & Slaney it is written that superior reconstructions are obtained by multiplying the transform of the image projections:

```
S(m * 2W/N)
```

( where N is the number of the samples, m is the index of the   samples: m=-N/2,...,0,...,N/2  and 1/(2W) is the sampling interval in the spacial domain )

by a Hamming window: H(m*2W/N).

But the analytic expression of the Hamming window is not written there.

I saw in matlab documentation that the expression of a Hamming window is :

```
w(n)=0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*n/N)   for  0<=n<=N
```

But is this in the spacial domain or in the frequency domain (in the later case should I fft this expression before multiplying it with the transform of the image projections)?

In "The measurement of power spectra" by Blackman & Tukey the Hamming window is given by:

```
D(tau)=0.54+0.46*cos(pi*tau/T)  for abs(tau)<T
```

This is given in the special domain.

The bottom line is that I do not know what expression should I use for the Hamming window:

```
 H(m*2W/N)
```

That is needed to be multiplied by the fourier transform of the image projection:

```
S(m * 2W/N).
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding why you're using a window in the first place.

A Fourier Transform of a finite segment of data is implemented by wrap around: f(t+T) = f(t). However, This means there's a periodic discontinuity. A window function removes these discontinuities by multiplying f(t)  with a window function that's zero around f(0) and f(T).

Obviously, as this window is applied prior to the FT, it has to happen in the input domain. (Spatial, in your case, but it could also be the time domain)

Comment: But Kak in his book explicitly says that the multiplication with the Hamming window should be in the frequency domain. My question is how this Hamming window should look like?

Comment: @user4861528: I don have the book; does he perhaps describe windowing before the **inverse** fourier transform? That's why I stress the need to understand what windowing does.

Comment: He doesn't talk about windowing at all before mentioning the the superiority of using Hamming window. But regarding the wrap around business he mentioned in his book that in order to avoid circular convolution (when calculating the convolution with Fourier transforms ) one should pad the data with zeros before applying the FFT. I can send you an electronic version of the book if you give me an email address or you can download the book from the site http://en.bookfi.org/.  The use of Hamming window is mentioned in page 66 and 75.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the book from the link you gave and to clarify a little bit:

1. A window function can be viewed as filter (although they are used in a different context), meaning that it is either; CONVOLUTION in TIME or MULTIPLICATION in FREQUENCY.
2. The formulae `H(m(2W/N))` is the ham77 (hamming window) in the frequency domain.
3. The formulae above is therefore MULTIPLIED by the FFT (or DFT) of the signal you want to window.
4. The expression H (hamming window in frequency domain, or FFT(h(t)) ) is quite complicated; you can see an example here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HammingWindow.html
5. Since the Fourier transform of a hamming window is a complicated formulae (as well as an aproximation) you should always express it as the FFT of h(t). In matlab it would be as easy as `fft(hamming(L),N)` where L is the length of the window (in time samples) and N is the number of bins in the fft (it is better to be a power of 2).

I hope this clarifies a little bit the use of windows and don't hesitate to comment if it is still not clear enough.